# Restricting Office 365 services to ip range

Tags: vpn, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

My company has a office 365 subscription so all our Outlook, OneDrive, Skype etc. infrastructure is hosted for us online. I am trying to restrict our emails to a range of ip addresses (as we have just implemented a vpn), but can't find anywhere in the admin or Security centers, or indeed in the docs that allow you to configure the firewall. This seems such a straight forwards thing that I am sure I've missed something.

Client Access Policies seem to only include docs for self hosted exchange servers etc.

Comment: `I am trying to restrict our emails to a range of ip addresses` - What do you mean exactly? Are you trying to restrict from where your users can connect to their email accounts?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, that's what I am after

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the IP ranges of clients, you have two options:

1. Sign up for Azure Active Directory Premium and setup conditional access.
2. Use ADFS and implement the restrictions in you on-premises Active Directory.